# Scrapy: Saving in JSON files with custom Directory within Spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I already know how to store scraped items in a JSON file using the command line. However, I would like:

1) to customize the directory where the JSON is saved

2) to customize the directory using variables in my Spider

Here are the first lines of my Spider:

```
import scrapy
import json
import math
import re
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from parsel import Selector

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "getaround"

    search_dates = ['2019-12-28']
    search_date = datetime.date(datetime.strptime(search_dates[0],'%Y-%m-%d'))

    crawlDate = search_date - timedelta(days=31)
    panelDay = search_date.strftime("%A")
    crawlDay = crawlDate.strftime("%A")

    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY' : True,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' : 6,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED' : True,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY' : 6,
        'LOG_STDOUT' : True,
        'LOG_FILE' : 'D:/Données/Drivy/' + search_dates[0] + '/' + 'log_' + str(crawlDate) + '_' + search_dates[0] + '.txt',
    }
```

I would like to tell the spider to register the JSON file containing the scraped items, in a directory which involves `search_dates[0]`. Moreover, the JSON file should contain `search_dates[0]` and `str(crawlDate)`. It already works with the log file. Anybody can help me with this issue ? Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read the documentation about exporting items? Did you read about the setting which determines the output file name? Have you tried using that setting?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've found the `FEED_FORMAT`and `FEED_URI` setting options which do the trick.